# Functional equivalent concatenating items in multiple lists of different lengths

Tags: powershell, functional-programming

What is the the functional style equivalent of this imperative code?
(This happens to be Powershell, but I’m interested in both Powershell and language-agnostic solutions.)

```
$part1=1,2
$part2='a','b','c'
$part3=1,2,3,4
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$n= @()

foreach($x in $part1)
{
    foreach($y in $part2)
    {
        foreach($z in $part3)
        {
            $n.Add("$x$y$z")
        }
    }
}

$n
```

And here are some handy tips for doing map, filter, and reduce in Powershell, showing that a functional style is possible: 
http://peterreavy.com/tech/2014/04/30/Map,-reduce-and-filter-in-PowerShell.html

Edit: The desired output is the collection containing 24 items: 
1a1, 1a2, 1a3, 1a4, 1b1, 1b2, 1b3, 1b4, 1c1, 1c2, 1c3, 1c4,
2a1, ..., 2a4, 2b1, ..., 2c4

Comment: you want to iterate part 3 multiple times? The innermost loop will execute 6 times...

Comment: I would like the innermost loop to execute 2 * 3 * 4 or 24 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that what's you are looking for, but you can write it like this :

```
$part1=1,2
$part2='a','b','c'
$part3=1,2,3,4

$n = $part1 | % {$a=$_;$part2 | %{$b=$_;$part3 | % {"$a$b$_"}}}
```

**Remark :**

You can write your code like this in powershell. `@()` is a collection and `+=` operate on collections adding an item. Be careful the `$n.Add("$x$y$z")` return an integer.

```
$part1=1,2
$part2='a','b','c'
$part3=1,2,3,4
$n= @()

foreach($x in $part1)
{
    foreach($y in $part2)
    {
        foreach($z in $part3)
        {
            $n += "$x$y$z"
        }
    }
}
$n
```

Comment: Thank you for the += warning. Add() does return an integer index of the added element.